# Taking the address of a boost::any variable

Tags: c++, boost

Consider:

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {

    //Code snippet 1
    boost::any variable(std::string("Hello "));
    std::string* string_ptr_any = boost::any_cast<std::string>(&variable);
    std::cout << "Pointer value is " << string_ptr_any <<", variable's address is " << &variable << std::endl;
    //End Code snippet 1

    //Code snippet 2
    std::string normalstring = "hello_normal";
    std::string* normalstringptr = &normalstring;
    std::cout << "Pointer value is " << normalstringptr << ", variable's address is " << &normalstring << std::endl;
    //End Code snippet 2

    //Code snippet 3
    std::string& reference_of_string = boost::any_cast<std::string&>(variable);
    reference_of_string += "World!";
    std::cout << reference_of_string << std::endl;
    std::cout << boost::any_cast<std::string>(variable) << std::endl;
    //End Code snippet 3    

    getchar();

}
```

Running this on [compiler explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/qf41YoGff) gives as output:

```
Pointer value is 0xc2feb8, variable's address is 0x7ffec1620d68
Pointer value is 0x7ffec1620d40, variable's address is 0x7ffec1620d40
Hello World!
Hello World!
```

(Q1) As expected, Code snippet 2 gives the same value for both the address of the variable as well as the pointer (`0x7ffec1620d40` in this case). But what explains the similar code in Code snippet 1 giving rise to two different addresses? (`0xc2feb8` vs `0x7ffec1620d68`) What is the relationship between these two addresses in memory?

(Q2) I am unable to see a consistent syntax rule to cast a `boost::any` variable. In Code snippet 1, to obtain a pointer, the syntax is:

`std::string* string_ptr_any = boost::any_cast<std::string>(&variable);`

while in Code snippet 3, to obtain a reference, the syntax is:

`std::string& reference_of_string = boost::any_cast<std::string&>(variable);`

More specifically, why is not the syntax in Code snippet 1:

`std::string* string_ptr_any = boost::any_cast<std::string*>(&variable);`

Is there a general rule of which these syntaxes are consistent special cases?

Comment: _"What is the relationship between these two addresses in memory?"_ — Learn how `any` works. It needs to apply _type erasure_. Comparing addresses of the `any` variable and the owned object does not make much sense. The owned object is usually stored in a dynamically-allocated storage (unless some small object optimization is applied). The first pointer points seemingly to the heap in your case. I don't understand what "does not work" here; everything seems to be fine.

Comment: @DanielLangr That compiles but does not work either: See https://compiler-explorer.com/z/a8bhGvEnc It does not "work" means that the addresses are different in Code snippet 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what explains the similar code in Code snippet 1 giving rise to two different addresses? (0xc2feb8 vs 0x7ffec1620d68) What is the relationship between these two addresses in memory?

`string_ptr_any` is the address of the `std::string` object. `&variable` is the address of the `boost::any` object.

---

> why is not the syntax in Code snippet 1:
>
> ```
> std::string* string_ptr_any = boost::any_cast<std::string*>(&variable);
> ```

Because the `boost::any` doesn't contain an object of type `std::string*`. You can only cast to the type that is contained, or a reference to it. This would be an alternative way to write snippet 1:

```
std::string* string_ptr_any = &boost::any_cast<std::string&>(variable);
```